# How to plot a specific region of a map?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot a specific part of Germany (German Bight). Therefore I used followig code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mapdata)

lon_min <- 5
lon_max <- 10
lat_min <- 52
lat_max <- 57

coast_map <- fortify(map("worldHires", 
                     xlim = c(lon_min, lon_max), 
                     ylim = c(lat_min, lat_max), 
                     fill = T, plot = F))

ggplot(coast_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
geom_polygon()
```

And this is the picture I get
[image: map of germany]

Well, this isn't really what I want to get. I don't want to plot hole Germany but a specific region of it. As you can see above, I definied longitude and latitude.

```
 lon_min <- 5
 lon_max <- 10
 lat_min <- 52
 lat_max <- 57
```

Why the entire map of Germany is shown to me? Is there a way to cut the map at corresponding coordinates while using geom_polygon()?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `+ coord_map(xlim=c(lon_min, lon_max), ylim=c(lat_min, lat_max))`.

Comment: perfectly fits. thanks a lot. sometimes it's just that easy

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? (code below)

[image: ggplot2 German Bight]

```
# install.packages("mapdata", dependencies = TRUE)
# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(mapdata)

lon_min <- 5
lon_max <- 10
lat_min <- 52
lat_max <- 57

coast_map <- fortify(map("worldHires", 
                     xlim = c(lon_min, lon_max), 
                     ylim = c(lat_min, lat_max), 
                     fill = T, plot = F))

ggplot(coast_map, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + geom_polygon() + 
       coord_map(xlim=c(lon_min, lon_max), ylim=c(lat_min, lat_max))
```